# Has or Have with Either of + pronoun

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Since "either" takes a singular verb, can we use "has" when a sentence uses "either of"?

> I don't think either of you has/have seen that creature.

Should this be "either of you has seen that creature"? (To mean "either one of you")?

Comment: Since you already know that _either_ takes the singular verb form, you know the answer. The preposition phrase after _either_ doesn't change it into a plural! Consider _either_ and _both_. _"I think **both** of you **have** seen that creature."_

Comment: Do you understand the relationship between _either_ (singular) and _both_ (plural)?

Comment: Yes. Both would refer to plural (as in two people together), while either would refer to (either this person or that person).

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  "Either" takes a singular verb.  Either has seen that creature.  ("Either have seen that creature" is incorrect.)

Answer (score 0):

"either" can take either plural or singular verbs. And in this case, the subject is "you", which is the second person. The second person is conjugated the same as plural third person, so "have" is preferable, but "has" is acceptable.

Comment: I think you are right that "have" is "preferable", in that most people *prefer* to say it, but I don't think that makes it "correct" from the standpoint of people trying to learn the formal rules of English grammar. The "subject" isn't "you", but "either", which really means "either one", and it takes a singular verb. [Picky? yes, sorry]